# Exclamation mark is missing after replacing characters in text file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use batch file to replace certain characters in text file. Everything else works fine except that the exclamation mark (!) is missing after running the batch file.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem delayed variable expansion, allowing variables to be expanded at execution time.

set "search=MMMMMMMMMM"
set "replace=WWWWWWWWWW"
set "inputFile=input.txt"
set "outputFile=output.txt"

(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputFile%" ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set "line=!line:*:=!"

    if defined line (
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        echo(!line!
    ) else echo.
)) > "%outputFile%"

endlocal
rem end local scope to clean up environment variable.
```

I googled some solution but couldn't find one that satisfies. Thanks.

In input.txt:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#MMMMMMMMMM
```

In output.txt:

```
#if defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#WWWWWWWWWW
```

Expected output.txt:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#WWWWWWWWWW
```

Comment: The trick is to toggle delayed expansion

Comment: Thanks Jeb. I fixed the problem by adding 'setlocal disableDelayedExpansion' and 'setlocal enableDelayedExpansion' for the inner loop.

Comment: Daniel Su, I have removed your previous edit. If you wish to provide solutions, those only belong in the answer area. Unfortunately as you solution is a duplicate, that option is unavailable to you. Your existing comment above should have been sufficient to inform future readers.